# Does linear discrete-time controllability imply stabilizability

Tags: dynamical-systems, control-theory, stability-theory, discrete-time

Does linear discrete-time controllability imply stabilizability?
I feel like it should, since controllability is the ability to steer from any state $x(0)$ to another state $x(1)$ in finite time and stabilizability is the ability to steer a system to zero, with a control input that can be defined over an infinite amount of time.
I would say that if a system $x(k+1) = Ax(k) + bu(k)$ is controllable, you can take $x(1)$ equal to 0 and you have stabilizability. However if I google this, I cannot find a clear answer and I'm questioning myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conceptually, controllability and stabilizability are different things. Controllability is an open-loop property of the system and gives the limit of the control input effect on the state response (see also my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3700849/on-steering-the-state-of-an-lti-system-to-a-desired-state-and-keeping-it-there/3703761#3703761)). Stabilizability is the existence of a static state feedback controller that stabilizes the system.

It turns out in LTI systems if the system is controllable then it is also stabilizable. But just taking $x(1)=0$ is not the way to prove this statement. It would only show the existence of a stabilizing control signal, but not a feedback controller. The actual proof is more involved and not intuitive or obvious (to me at least).

Having said that, you can probably find some "definitions" out there such as: "stabilizability is defined as the stability of the uncontrollable nodes". This is true for LTI systems but not in general. In my opinion it shouldn't be a definition since it can actually be proven from more general concepts. Also, it doesn't give the intuition that a definition should give.